# How to add light box on react

Tags: reactjs, lightbox

I'm trying to use the Simple React Lightbox (SRL), from https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-react-lightbox, but I it doesn't work. It seems simple but I guess I'm doing something wrong. I want when I click the image link, a light box with the same image to open. I tried making my own lightbox in different component but it still doesn't work.

my code

```
import logo from './movieBrowser.jpg';
import logo2 from './portfolio-2.jpg';
import logo3 from './portfolio-3.jpg';
import logo4 from './portfolio-4.jpg';
import { SRLWrapper } from "simple-react-lightbox";

const Projects = () =>{
return(
  <div id="project">
      <div className="container-fluid p-2 mb-0 ">
          <div className="row g-0 m-4">
          <SRLWrapper>
              <div className="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 p-1">
                  <a className="portfolio-box"  href={logo3} title="Project Name">
                      <img className="img-fluid" src={logo3} alt="ptoject name" />
                      <div className="portfolio-box-caption">
                          <div className="project-category text-white-50">Category</div>
                          <div className="project-name">Project Name</div>
                      </div>
                  </a>
              </div>
              </SRLWrapper>
              <div className="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 p-1">
                  <a className="portfolio-box" href={logo4} title="Project Name">
                      <img className="img-fluid" src={logo4} alt="..." />
                      <div className="portfolio-box-caption">
                          <div className="project-category text-white-50">Category</div>
                          <div className="project-name">Project Name</div>
                      </div>
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 p-1">
                  <a className="portfolio-box"  href={logo2} title="Project Name">
                      <img className="img-fluid" src={logo2} alt="..." />
                      <div className="portfolio-box-caption">
                          <div className="project-category text-white-50">Category</div>
                          <div className="project-name">Project Name</div>
                      </div>
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 p-1">
                  <a className="portfolio-box"  href={logo} title="Project Name">
                      <img className="img-fluid" src={logo} alt="..." />
                      <div className="portfolio-box-caption">
                          <div className="project-category text-white-50">Category</div>
                          <div className="project-name">Project Name</div>
                      </div>
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 p-1">
                  <a className="portfolio-box" href={logo4} title="Project Name">
                      <img className="img-fluid" src={logo4} alt="..." />
                      <div className="portfolio-box-caption">
                          <div className="project-category text-white-50">Category</div>
                          <div className="project-name">Project Name</div>
                      </div>
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 p-1">
                  <a className="portfolio-box"  href={logo3} title="Project Name">
                      <img className="img-fluid" src={logo3} alt="..." />
                      <div className="portfolio-box-caption p-3">
                          <div className="project-category text-white-50">Category</div>
                          <div className="project-name">Project Name</div>
                      </div>
                  </a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

)
}
export default Projects;
```

Comment: Maybe try this one instead - https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/react

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I figured it out, i had to remove the divs inside the links so it works.